# counter variable inside a setInterval function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have set one scroll-counter variable(it counts the number of scroll occured) inside the setInterval function which increases by 1 every-time the setInterval function is executed(the setInterval function runs 20 times and stops) and its value is displayed in the page. But the value immediately gets to maximum even before all the setInterval functions are completed executing.

I am sorry if it's a bad explanation, hope this code clears my question.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pagePos = 0;
  var point = 0;

  $(".nav-btn").click(function() {
    var intervalid = setInterval(function() {
      pagePos = pagePos + 200;
      $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: +pagePos
      }, 500);
      point = point + 1;
      $('.scroll-count').text("Scroll count: " + point);
      if (pagePos >= 4000) {
        clearInterval(intervalid);
        point = 0;
        pagePos = 0;
      }
    }, 50);

  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-class {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-btn {
  background-color: bisque;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 5em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.nav-btn:hover {
  border: 2px solid rgb(76, 0, 255);
}

.inner-div-class {
  border: 1px solid rebeccapurple;
  height: 300px;
}

.div-class>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: violet;
}

.div-class>div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: palegreen;
}

.scroll-count {
  position: fixed;
  top: 85%;
  left: 1em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-shadow: 2.5px 1.5px 0px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Jquery auto scroll</title>
</head>


<body>
  <nav class="nav-class">
    <button class="nav-btn"> Click </button><span style="font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif"> to start scrolling</span>
  </nav>
  <div class="div-class">
    <div class="inner-div-class"></div>
    <div class="inner-div-class"></div>
    <div class="inner-div-class"></div>
    <div class="inner-div-class"></div>
    <div class="inner-div-class"></div>
    <div class="inner-div-class"></div>
    <div class="inner-div-class"></div>
    <div class="inner-div-class"></div>
    <div class="inner-div-class"></div>
    <div class="inner-div-class"></div>
    <div class="inner-div-class"></div>
    <div class="inner-div-class"></div>
    <div class="inner-div-class"></div>
    <div class="inner-div-class"></div>
    <div class="inner-div-class"></div>
    <div class="inner-div-class"></div>
    <div class="inner-div-class"></div>
    <div class="inner-div-class"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-count">
    Scroll count:
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post only pertinent code. If this is purely a JS issue, we don't need your entire CSS and HTML too, just the JS.

Comment: "the value immediately gets to maximum"  That's not the behavior I'm seeing. (it's on a very short interval, though, only 50ms; perhaps you need to slow it down?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pagePos = 0;
  var point = 0;

  $(".nav-btn").click(function() {
    var intervalid = setInterval(function() {
      pagePos = pagePos + 200;
      $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: +pagePos
      }, 500);
      point = point + 1;
      $('.scroll-count').text("Scroll count: " + point);
      if (pagePos >= 4000) {
        clearInterval(intervalid);
        point = 0;
        pagePos = 0;
      }
    }, 500); <HERE

  });
});
```

Change the 50 interval to 500

Comment: thanks @Ibraheem Ghaffar, I didn't notice that the animation speed is more than the setInterval time.